# Text Classification in spacy v3

Tags: spacy, text-classification

I am trying to perform a text classification using spacy v3.

I am a bit confused with CLI approach. However, following the examples in the spacy project repo [HERE](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/tutorials).

I downloaded test data right [HERE](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/koaning/tokenwiser/main/data/oos-intent.jsonl) and prepared it to spacy v3 format:

```py
import pandas as pd
from spacy.tokens import DocBin
import spacy

nlp = spacy.blank("en")
doc_bin = DocBin()

df= pd.read_json("../data/data.jsonl", lines = True)
df.head()

doc_bin = DocBin()

for text, label in zip(df['text'], df['label']):
    doc = nlp(text)
    doc.cats[label] = True
    doc_bin.add(doc)

doc_bin.to_disk('train.spacy')
```

Created a textclassification `config.cfg` file on the documentation page.

And start the training loop given as:

```py
python -m spacy train assets/config.cfg --output training/ --paths.train assets/train.spacy --paths.dev assets/train.spacy
```

I get the following output:

```sh
Some weights of the model checkpoint at roberta-base were not used when initializing RobertaModel: ['lm_head.bias', 'lm_head.decoder.weight', 'lm_head.layer_norm.bias', 'lm_head.layer_norm.weight', 'lm_head.dense.bias', 'lm_head.dense.weight']
- This IS expected if you are initializing RobertaModel from the checkpoint of a model trained on another task or with another architecture (e.g. initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForPreTraining model).
- This IS NOT expected if you are initializing RobertaModel from the checkpoint of a model that you expect to be exactly identical (initializing a BertForSequenceClassification model from a BertForSequenceClassification model).
[2022-05-16 04:50:42,566] [INFO] Initialized pipeline components: ['transformer', 'textcat']
✔ Initialized pipeline

============================= Training pipeline =============================
ℹ Pipeline: ['transformer', 'textcat']
ℹ Initial learn rate: 0.0
E    #       LOSS TRANS...  LOSS TEXTCAT  CATS_SCORE  SCORE 
---  ------  -------------  ------------  ----------  ------
```

And it seems that the pipeline has started. However, nothing else is happening. Apparently no training is happening and I only see first empty row of training loop.

Comment: Is it possible you're using a Transformer without a GPU? That would be very slow. You would need to at least specify `-g 0` in your `spacy train` command to get GPU training. I would also recommend you try training a model without Transformers first to make sure your data is OK.

Comment: HAHA!, seems like it. Thank you so much. While we are at it do you happen to now a documentation with detailed explanation of ```config.cfg``` file?

Comment: I cannot find eval basic setting such as number of epochs in config file

Comment: If you use the search function on the spaCy website you'll find all kinds of documentation for the config file, including training epochs.